# How do I pass a parameter in a string in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to delete an item on a list by passing the task ID in an a href link in thymeleaf. This is what it looks like

```
<a th:href="@{'delete-task?id='${task.id}}">
```

But instead of deleting the item this is the output

```
delete-task?id=th:text=%27${task.id}%27
```

Im getting this error in the slack trace

```
 : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
Can anyone tell me the correct syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your href should look more like that:

```
<a th:href="@{'delete-task?id=' + ${task.id}}"></a>
```

Comment: Can you help me with another thymeleaf issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064706/spring-boot-thymeleaf-form-error

Answer (score 2):

You should be using thymeleaf's [Standard URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) for links -- so that parameters can be correctly url escaped.  Your link should look like this:

```
<a th:href="@{delete-task(id=${task.id})}">
```